# Check if video, image file exists iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm getting paths in an iOS app like:

```
AVURLAsset* urlAsset = (AVURLAsset*)asset;
NSString *filePath = [urlAsset.URL path];
NSURL *videoUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
```

Result:

```
file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/105APPLE/IMG_5255.MOV
```

This app uploads files, in this case a video, but once I delete the video and go back to the app, this causes issues at the time that the app tries to upload the erased file, is there a way to check if the file exists to prevent issues while running the app? And also does the path changes when it's moved to "Recently Deleted" folder using iOS > 10?

In android is simple as

```
File file = new File(filePath);
if(file.exists())      
//Do something
else
// Do something else.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either `checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:` or `fileExistsAtPath:`.

```
if([videoUrl checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:NULL] == YES) {
    //Use file
}
```

or

```
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:videoUrl.path] {
    //Use file
}
```